# How can I navigate in electron app from system tray icon

Tags: angular, electron

I made a web app with Angular now I want to transform it into desktop application. I'm new to Electron and the thing I'm trying to achieve is to have navigation bar on tray icon.

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
    { path: '/devices', title: 'devices', icon: 'phonelink_setup', class: '' },
    { path: '/documents', title: 'documents', icon: 'description', class: '' },
    { path: '/users', title: 'users', icon: 'groups', class: '' }
];
```

For example, I can navigate between document, user and device pages. Now, I would like to make that those routs were inside my tray menu for desktop application.

Code for what I made until now:

```
tray = new Tray(__dirname + '/src/logo.ico');
tray.setToolTip("my-app");
tray.setContextMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Show app', click: () => {
            mainWindow.show();
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Quit', click: () => {
            quiting = true;
            app.quit();
        }
    }
]));
tray.on('double-click', (event) => {
    mainWindow.show();
});
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I found the solution. I can use this code for any route I need:

```
{
    label: "Devices",
    click: () => {
        mainWindow.loadURL(`file:///${path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`)}#/devices`)
        if (!mainWindow.isVisible()) mainWindow.show();
    }
}
```